# Error "The password field is requiered!" Laravel

Tags: laravel, passwords, registration

I use the standard registration and login of Laravel. I have adapted this to my needs and extended a few fields. But always i get the error message "The password field is requiered" when i make a new user. Where does this error message come from?

web.php

```
// Registration Routes...
Route::get('index', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
Route::post('index', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

index.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="row pt-100">
        <h2>xyz</h2>
                        <form class="nomargin sky-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <fieldset>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="name">name</label>
                                            <label class="input margin-bottom-10">
                                                <i class="ico-append fa fa-user"></i>
                                                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>
                                                <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Dein Name</b>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 mtm-15">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="username">username</label>
                                            <label class="input margin-bottom-10">
                                                <i class="ico-append fa fa-user"></i>
                                                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus>
                                                <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Dein Username</b>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 mtm-15">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="email">email</label>
                                            <label class="input margin-bottom-10">
                                                <i class="ico-append fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                                <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="eMail" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
                                                <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Deine eMail</b>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 mtm-15">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="password">password</label>
                                            <label class="input margin-bottom-10">
                                                <i class="ico-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                                                <input type="password" id="password" minlength="6" placeholder="Passwort" requiered>
                                                <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Min. 6 Zeichen lang</b>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

              <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('gender') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <div class="col-md-3 pt-3">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="male">male</label>
                                            <label class="radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender" requiered autofocus>
                        <i></i> <span style="color:white">Männlich</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 pt-3">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="female">female</label>
                                            <label class="radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender" requiered autofocus>
                    <i></i> <span style="color:white">Weiblich</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                                    </div>

                                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('birthday') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <div class="col-md-6 mtm-15">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="birthday">birthday</label>
                                            <label class="input margin-bottom-10">
                                            <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday" value="{{ old('date') }}" placeholder="Geburtsdatum" requiered autofocus>
                                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Dein Geburtsdatum</b>
                                        </label>
                </div>
                    </div>
                            </div>

                                <div class="row form-group {{ $errors->has('agb') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-20">
                                        <label class="checkbox nomargin">
                                            <input class="checked-agree" type="checkbox" id="agb" value="agree" required>
                                            <i></i>
                                            <span style="color:white">Hiermit bestätige ich die </span>
                                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termsModal">AGB/Datenschutzerklärung</a>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> REGISTRIEREN</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
        </div>
```

migration

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->text('biografie');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->date('birthday');
            $table->text('privacy');
            $table->string('agb');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

user.php

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'username', 'gender', 'birthday', 'agb'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

registercontroller

```
   protected function validator(array $data)
        {
            return Validator::make($data, [
                'name' => 'required|string|max:30',
                'username' => 'required|string|max:20|unique:users',
                'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
                'gender' => 'required|string',
                'birthday' => 'required|date',
                'agb' => 'required|string',
            ]);
        }

        /**
         * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
         *
         * @param  array  $data
         * @return \App\User
         */
        protected function create(array $data)
        {
            return User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'username' => $data['username'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                'gender' => $data['gender'],
                'birthday' => $data['birthday'],
                'agb' => $data['agb'],
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing **name** attribute in the input field.

Just Change your input field.

```
<input type="password" id="password" minlength="6" name="password" placeholder="Password" requiered>
```

Now, you will get an error of Invalid confirmation password because you are missing password_confirmation input field.

Include Password Confirmation field in your registration form.

```
<input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
```

You're good to go.

Comment: Thank you.
I have edited the register controller and removed "confirmed". But the data is not written to the database. I get no error message.
you know where the problem is?

Comment: Hard to decode a bug on my side. Try to create a user with dummy values.

Comment: Try few commands: `php artisan optimize` , `php artisan view:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I want to create a new User with dummy values and the Input fields from Index.blade.php But the Data is not in the Database and i get no error message. How can i find the error?

Comment: Did you run `php artisan migrate` after creating the schema?

Comment: I have run all commands but the problem is the same. The Data is not in the database and i get no error message. This is a strange problem.